# Google Visualization Pie Charts in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to display pie chart on lightning component. I was referring this link [Google Visualization Pie Chart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#overview) to create chart on lightning component but it not work. when i check my console log i am getting error message.[image]

lightning component:-

```
<aura:component >
Hello from Lightning Component.....
<ltng:require styles="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/44/css/util/util.css" scripts="/resource/loader" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}"/>
<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</aura:component>
```

lightning controller:-

```
({
    afterScriptsLoaded : function(component, event, helper) {
       // debugger;
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
         function drawChart() {
        //debugger;
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
        //var chart = component.find("piechart").getElement()
        chart.draw(data, options);  
    }
    },
})
```

Please help me how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because your CSS file can't be loaded from external server . Lightning will block any external callout from client side for security reasons .

You can store the CSS file inside static resource and reference the same in your component .

Comment: @ Mohith i will try this but i did not get any output.

Comment: Check your console to see if any other issues

Comment: Hello Mohith  Now i was getting same message Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://www.gstatic.com/charts/44/css/util/util.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' chrome-extension: 'unsafe-inline'".

Comment: So yes your CSS file is again referencing from external source. Download that and keep all in static resource

Comment: I download it use this css file through static resource but i still get same error message.

Comment: Your CSS file reference another CSS file from external service.  Unless you download all and modify the reference this error will not go